# first item used by a user

Tags: mysql, group-by, inner-join

I am writing a query to grab the items that a specific user_id was the first to use. Here is some sample data -

```
item_id used_user_id    date_used
1       1               2012-08-25
1       2               2012-08-26               
1       3               2012-08-27
2       2               2012-08-27
3       1               2012-08-27
4       1               2012-08-21
4       3               2012-08-24
5       3               2012-08-23
```

query

```
select item_id as inner_item_id, ( select used_user_id 
                                   from test 
                                   where test.item_id = inner_item_id 
                                   order by date_used asc 
                                   limit 1 ) as first_to_use_it 
from test 
where used_user_id = 1 
group by item_id
```

It returns the correct values

```
inner_item_id   first_to_use_it
1               1
3               1
4               1
```

but the query is VERY slow on a giant table. Is there a certain index that I can use or a better query that I can write?

Comment: You can't know what particular user was the first to use an item without adding a timestamp to your table. It seems you are currently resorting to the `used_user_id` for this but while that works for your given inputs, that can't possibly return what you require from your actual data.

Comment: added date_used so that it makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i can't get exactly what you mean because in your inner query you have sorted it by their `used_user_id` and and on your outer query you have filtered it also by their userid. Why not do this directly?

```
SELECT DISTINCT item_id AS inner_item_id,
       used_user_id AS first_to_use_it 
FROM   test
WHERE  used_user_id = 1
```

**UPDATE 1**

```
SELECT  b.item_id, 
        b.used_user_id AS first_to_use_it
FROM
    (
        SELECT item_ID, MIN(date_used) minDate
        FROM tableName
        GROUP BY item_ID
    ) a
        INNER JOIN tableName b
            ON a.item_ID = b.item_ID AND
                a.minDate = b.date_used
WHERE   b.used_user_id = 1
```

Comment: I have the inner query sorted because there could be hundreds of users that use an item, but I want to make sure that the user_id is the FIRST user to use it not just the user with the lowest id.

Comment: For example, if you put in used_user_id = 2 in your query, it returns 3 items when it should only return the item_id of 2.

Comment: so what is your basis to know that that `userid` was the first one to use? do you have any dates?

Comment: I think he uses order of insertion

Comment: @Giuseppe if that is his basis then its wrong. basically the server inserts the record in any row. but it can be done if the OP has primary key (autoincremented value) or a date when it was inserted. :D

Comment: @JohnWoo absolutely. I was assuming there is a primary key. otherways there must be a date. In any case some info is missing

Comment: added date_used so that it makes sense. user_id used it the earliest.

Comment: @John love the query, works great. But do you know where I can place an index or two to make it faster? The group by item_ID is taking a while.

Comment: do you have an index on this column? `item_ID`